# How to query a List of objects as Map in Spring data Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to query a complex object with sub fields, I do not want to setup all fields but I need them.

On my repository, when I search for an object passing `Map.class` it woks ok, but when I pass an entity with a `Map` property, it rises a `NullPointerException`

```java
elasticSearchOperations.get(id, Map.class, IndexCoordinates.of(index))
```

My class that does not work is like:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Todo {

    @Field(name = "entries", type = FieldType.Object)
    private List<Map> entries;

    public Todo() {
        this.entries = Lists.newArrayList();
    }

}
```

Here is the sample mapping, there are a lot of fields that a do not want to map on a class, that is why I am using `Map.class` interface.

```
{
   "todo":{
      "mappings":{
         "properties":{
            "_created":{
               "type":"date"
            },
            "_created_user":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "entries":{
               "properties":{
                  "_created":{
                     "type":"date"
                  },
                  "_id":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "_updated":{
                     "type":"date"
                  },
                  "what":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

> PS.: I do not make a service to index documents, my service only search them.

Comment: Can you share index mapping as well ?

Comment: The second parameter of `DocumentOperations.get(String, java.lang.Class<T>, IndexCoordinates)` is the entity class, here that might be `Todo`. `Map.class` is no entity class, but an interface, so it's not clear what you have stored and what you want to rertrieve

Comment: @SahilGupta I just update the question

Comment: @P.J.Meisch, when I use `Map.class` directly for search, it works as expected. But when I use `Map.class` on a class property it crashes when I search for them.